# Modifying a function used as a column default in SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql, function, constraints

We're having an issue with a poorly coded SQL function(which works fine in live, but not in our test environment). This function is used to provide a default value in many tables, trying to ALTER the function returns a "Cannot ALTER ### because it is being referenced by object" error.

Is there any way round this error message? The only way I can think of is attempting to write a script to remove it from every table that has it as a default, altering the function and re-adding it after.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since the object is referenced, you cannot modify it. This is what you do:

1. Remove the default constraint from the table/column
2. Modify the function
3. Add the default constraint back

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server will not allow you to modify a function that is bound to the DEFAULT constraint of a column.

Your only option is to remove the constraint before altering the function. ([Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/3a411944-4f74-4553-a511-c066bd495a2a))

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to

1. delete all default constrains that contains your function
2. modify your function
3. and then reinsert all those deleted constrains

You can store in a temporal table the constrains that you are going to delete/reinsert that contains your function, like

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table (query_delete VARCHAR(1000), query_create VARCHAR(1000));

INSERT INTO temp_table (query_delete, query_create)
SELECT
'ALTER TABLE ' + schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name] + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + [constraint].[name] + ';' as query_delete,
'ALTER TABLE ' + schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name] + ' ADD CONSTRAINT ' + [constraint].[name] + ' DEFAULT my_function() FOR ' + [column].[name] + ';' as query_create
FROM sys.default_constraints [constraint]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.objects t
        ON [constraint].parent_object_id = t.object_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.all_columns [column]
        ON [constraint].parent_column_id = [column].column_id
        AND [constraint].parent_object_id = [column].object_id
WHERE [constraint].[definition] = '(my_function())';
```

then performs step 1 (delete all default constrains that contains your function)

```
DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT query_delete, query_create FROM temp_table;

DECLARE @query_delete VARCHAR(1000), @query_create VARCHAR(1000);

OPEN table_cursor;  
FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @query_delete, @query_create;  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN
    PRINT @query_delete;
    --PRINT @query_create;
    EXEC (@query_delete);
    FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @query_delete, @query_create;  
END;  
CLOSE table_cursor;
DEALLOCATE table_cursor;
```

step 2 (modify your function)

```
ALTER FUNCTION my_function()
RETURNS -- return type
AS
BEGIN
   -- modify code
   RETURN -- return value
END
```

step 3 (reinsert all those deleted constrains)

```
DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT query_delete, query_create FROM temp_table;

DECLARE @query_delete VARCHAR(1000), @query_create VARCHAR(1000);

OPEN table_cursor;  
FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @query_delete, @query_create;  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN
    --PRINT @query_delete;
    PRINT @query_create;
    EXEC (@query_create);
    FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @query_delete, @query_create;  
END;  
CLOSE table_cursor;
DEALLOCATE table_cursor;
```

don't forget to delete the temporal table

```
DROP TABLE temp_table;
```

Comment: I didn't use this exact script but it provided all the direction that I needed to create my own.

In the end I generated a script which I then ran manually.